# Running RSpec specs with docker and docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec

I'm building a simple RoR application using Docker and docker-compose for faciliting my development setup.

The application is running with no problems with Docker/docker-compose but, when I'm trying to run RSpec spec with it, the Puma runs but specs not. See below:

```
# With Docker only:
$ docker container run simpleblogapp bundle exec rspec
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development 
    => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Puma version: 5.5.0 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Zawgyi")
    *  Min threads: 5
    *  Max threads: 5
    *  Environment: development
    *          PID: 7
    * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    Use Ctrl-C to stop

# With docker-compose
    $ docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" simpleblogapp bundle exec rsepc
    Creating simple_blog_app_simpleblogapp_run ... done
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in test 
    => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Puma version: 5.5.0 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Zawgyi")
    *  Min threads: 5
    *  Max threads: 5
    *  Environment: test
    *          PID: 7
    * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I'm run the RSpec directly, without Docker/docker-compose, it's works fine.

This is my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:3.0.2-alpine3.14

# install Ruby on Rails 6
RUN apk update \
  && apk add --update --no-cache \
    build-base \
    curl-dev \
    git \
    sqlite-dev \
    yaml-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    nodejs \
    yarn

WORKDIR /simple_blog_app
COPY Gemfile /simple_blog_app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /tmp/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler --no-document
RUN bundle config --local disable_platform_warnings true
RUN bundle install --no-binstubs --jobs $(nproc)
COPY . /simple_blog_app

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh" ]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "--binding", "0.0.0.0"]



# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  simpleblogapp:
    image: simpleblogapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

PS: I'm recently chance my SO to Ubuntu, where it was run normally, for Fedora Workstation 34.

Comment: What's in the `entrypoint.sh` script?  (Does it `exec "$@"` to run the command you're providing?)

Comment: The entrypoint.sh is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rvlaraujo/fe621791048011b4331e61fd36f9b0e3).

How you can see, I'm following the Docker documentation for RoR applications.

Comment: I've reinstall docker and it's works. Thanks, [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze).